# Cannot connect to ghost server on ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ghost-blog

I am following the basic Ghost server installation on an ec2 instance, so far I can run ghost server via `npm start` and I can see that ghost server is up and running:

```
Ghost is running... 
Listening on 127.0.0.1:2368 
Url configured as: http://54.187.25.187/ 
Ctrl+C to shut down
```

Here is the ghost config `config.js`:

```
// ### Development **(default)**
development: {
    // The url to use when providing links to the site, E.g. in RSS and email.
    url: 'http://54.187.25.187/',

    database: {
        client: 'sqlite3',
        connection: {
            filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost-dev.db')
        },
        debug: false
    },
    server: {
        // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
        port: '2368'
    }
```

At the end, I cannot access to anything when I type `http://54.187.25.187:2368` on the browser. I really appreciate guidelines on how to setup ghost properly.

EDIT: The problem is solved already, it was a EC2 SG issue that ports remained closed after I have set them to open.

Comment: Did you open the port on EC2 Security Groups?

Comment: Yes, all TCP ports are open.

Comment: Have you opened the port on the firewall not just in the VM security groups?

Comment: Supposed to close the question years ago, it was an EC2 SG issue at the end.

Answer (score 2):

For Amazon EC2 we have found you need to change the port to 0.0.0.0

http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-setup-an-amazon-ec2-instance-to-host-ghost-for-free-self-install/